# How to place a search box on middle of a carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make something like http://www.zoomcar.com/

This is my carousel code using amazing slider.

```html
<div id="amazingslider-wrapper-1" style="display:block;position:relative;max-width:100%;margin:0 auto;">
  <div class="form-group">    
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Where do you wanna go?">  
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="start" placeholder="Check In">   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <input type="date" class="form-control input-lg" name="end" placeholder="Check Out">            
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" href="#" role="button">GO</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:0 auto;">
    <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
      <li><img src="images/example-slide-1.jpg" alt="example-slide-1" />
      </li>
      <li><img src="images/example-slide-2.jpg" alt="example-slide-2" />
      </li>
      <li><img src="images/example-slide-3.jpg" alt="example-slide-3" />
      </li>
      <li><img src="images/example-slide-4.jpg" alt="example-slide-4" data-texteffect="Bottom bar" data-duration="2000" />
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="amazingslider-thumbnails" style="display:none;">
      <li><img src="images/example-slide-1-tn.jpg" alt="example-slide-1" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/example-slide-2-tn.jpg" alt="example-slide-2" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/example-slide-3-tn.jpg" alt="example-slide-3" /></li>
      <li><img src="images/example-slide-4-tn.jpg" alt="example-slide-4" /></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

How to add form control to the middle of the slider.

Please help me..

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Clarity of the question is not good.

Answer (score 0):

put your input fields in a `div` and place the `div` inside of `amazingslider`. then give it following css :

```
    div
    { 
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 10;
        /* and other properties */
                .
                .
                .
    }
```